# Error al publicar aplicación web ASP.NET en IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, iis

Tengo el siguiente error al hacer `publish` a una página web en el `iis` de mi maquina local, si hago `debug` funciona bien pero no al publicar desde `Visual Studio`, si copeo la carpeta del proyecto funciona sin ningún problema pero no puedo pasar los archivos al servidor ya que no hay un usuario o contraseña para `ftp`, ya me proporcionaron un archivo para publicarlo desde el `Visual Studio`

---

Este es el error al abrir http://localhost/ControlCobranza

## Error de servidor en la aplicación '/ControlCobranza'.

#### No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Microsoft.AI.Web' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

**Descripción:** Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

**Detalles de la excepción:** System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Microsoft.AI.Web' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

**Error de código fuente:**

> Se ha generado una excepción no controlada durante la ejecución de la
>   solicitud Web actual. La información sobre el origen y la ubicación de
>   la excepción pueden identificarse utilizando la excepción del
>   seguimiento de la pila siguiente.

**Rastro al cargar el ensamblado:** La información siguiente puede ser útil para determinar porqué no se cargó el ensamblado 'Microsoft.AI.Web'.

> AVS: El registro del enlace de ensamblado está desactivado. Para
>   habilitar el registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado, establezca
>   el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]
>   (DWORD) como 1. Nota: existe una disminución del rendimiento asociada
>   registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado. Para desactivar esta
>   característica, elimine el valor de Registro
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

**Seguimiento de la pila:**

> [FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado
>   'Microsoft.AI.Web' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede
>   encontrar el archivo especificado.]
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName) +106    System.RuntimeType.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
>   reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +62
>   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean
>   ignoreCase) +50    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +61
>   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String
>   propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node,
>   Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +53
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: No se puede cargar el archivo o
>   ensamblado 'Microsoft.AI.Web' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema
>   no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String
>   propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node,
>   Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +587
>   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String
>   propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean
>   checkAptcaBit) +33
>   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String
>   typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +57
>   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String
>   typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +54
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1
>   moduleList) +198
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext)
>   +1114    System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +140
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +402
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +343
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): No se puede cargar el archivo o
>   ensamblado 'Microsoft.AI.Web' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema
>   no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +539
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +125    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +731

**Información de versión:** Versión de Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319; Versión ASP.NET:4.6.1586.0

Comment: Dices que la URL local funciona sin problemas cuando le das F5 para ejecutar y depurar. Pero al momento que le das en publicar en tu local IIS e ir a la URL http://localhost/ControlCobranza te lanza el error. Lo estás haciendo desde WebDeploy (publish) por lo que veo, me confirmas estos datos mi estimado?

Comment: @fredyfx así es, incluso si creo una nueva web en http://localhost:81 lanza el mismo error

Comment: estás siguiendo todos estos pasos: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/8ef97c/how-to-publish-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-mvc-5-0-part-3/ ?

Comment: Si, pero cuando uso WebDeploy falla al hacer la publicación, y si selecciono FileSystem hace la publicación exitosa pero me lanza el error `/controlcobranza` en la web

Comment: Hola, ¿Tienes marcado Copia local=true en la referencia `Microsoft.AI.Web`?

Comment: @rsciriano tengo esta configuración que esta por defecto en system.web`<httpModules><add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/></httpModules>` y esta en system.webserver `<add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es posible que el error se produzca porque al hacer deploy no se incluya el ensamblado `Microsoft.AI.Web`

Para hacer que este ensamblado se incluya en el deploy tienes que marcar la opción `Copia local=true` como se muestra en la imagen

[image: Copia local=true]

También tienes que hacer lo mismo con `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights`, y el resto de ensamblados que necesite la aplicación y no estén en el [GAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/yf1d93sz(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Actualización:**

Según comenta [JuankGlezz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6635/juankglezz), el problema estaba en las referencias y se arregló **actualizandolas** con el control de **paquetes Nuget**.

Una vez arreglado este problema también se producía este otro error al publicar mediante **Webdeploy**:

> Web deployment task failed. (Esta lista de control de acceso no está en formato canónico y, por lo tanto, no se puede modificar.)

Este error tenía que ver con un problema de configuración de permisos en IIS y se corrige siguiendo los pasos descritos en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648654/publishing-website-error-this-access-control-list-is-not-in-canonical-form-and/35968313#35968313) de S.O. en inglés

1. Ir a IIS
2. Hacer click con el botón derecho en el sitio web publicado y seleccionar **Editar permisos**
3. Hacer click en tab de **Seguridad**
4. Hacer click en **Editar** y aparecerá un mensaje diciendo que los permisos no están ordenados correctamente
5. Hacer click en el botón **Reordenar** de la ventana de mensaje

[image: Reordenar permisos]

Comment: los tengo tal cual como mencionas y sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: @JuankGlezz si no vas a monitorizar la aplicación podrías quitar la configuración que mencionas. Otra cosa que puedes hacer es habilitar el fusión Log para obtener más información de porque no encuentra el ensamblado. También podrías revisar en local los ensamblados que está copiando en la publicación...

Comment: intente hacer lo de fusion Log y no me funciono, lo que hice fue actualizar las referencias con el control de paquetes Nuget y se solvento el problema, pero no me permite hacer el publish por WebDeploy únicamente con File System, cuando lo hago con webdeploy marca este error `Web deployment task failed. (Esta lista de control de acceso no está en formato canónico y, por lo tanto, no se puede modificar.)`

Comment: @JuankGlezz ¿donde te da el error? Al publicar en local o en remoto? Parece que es un problema de configuración de permisos en IIS, en local podrías solucionarlo como dice en [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35968313/1724791) respuesta de S.O. en inglés

Comment: El error es de manera local, funciono lo de la respuesta de SOen ya que también sucedía en remoto, crees que puedas adaptar tu respuesta en base a los comentarios (actualizar las referencias y lo de la respuesta de SOes), ya que las dos cosas formaron parte del problema, saludos

Comment: Hola @JuankGlezz, me alegro que te haya funcionado. Y como decías, he actualizado la respuesta con lo de los comentarios que así podrá ayudar más gente :-) Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Yo tuve el mismo error, pero me pasó debido a que tenía deshabilitado los servicios de IIS, busca la opción de **Activar o desactivar las características de Windows** y busca Internet Information Services, active las caracteristicas que necesitaba.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero esto contribuya, aunque al inicio, realice todos los pasos mostrados en la parte superior, pero no hay que descartar esta opción, donde posiblemente tengas deshabilitado el servicio de Internet Information Services.

Comment: El servicio si estaba habilitado, mi problema era el orden de los permisos de la carpeta donde se debería publicar el sitio de manera local, por otro lado si el servicio no estuviera levantado no me permitiría ver la página de error y me habria mostrado otro mensaje.

Answer (score -1):

Yo tenía el mismo problema y lo solucioné según se indica en esta **[respuesta en Stack Overflow *en inglés*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10200818/6744735)**:

1. Create a new application pool
2. Go to the Advanced Settings of this application pool
3. Set the Enable 32-Bit Application to True
4. Point your web application to use this new pool

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, Bernabé y **[bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** para conocer mas acerca del sitio. También puedes ver [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.